Can "after" be used alone by native English speakers?
Family are at dinner table, and a girl and the father are talking:
A: I am not being funny but I feel like a drink.
B: I will take you and your sister to the Rovers, after. Soap opera - Coronation Street (see 5:05-5:10)
The usage of "after" caught my attention. As far as I know, it is not used alone, rather it should be "after something".
Still, to make sure, I made a quick research, and verified that "After" is not usually used alone as an adverb from this grammer web site. Cohesion
So, why might it have been used in the conversation in a native english soap opera, or is it simply all right in non-standard English?

Pretty normal in regional UK Northern dialect (Corrie is set in the Manchester area).

Yes, seems natural to me as well. I suggest you watch that episode again, but start a few minutes earlier. I'm fairly sure you will find there is a context that makes sense of it. (For example, maybe they are at work so the listener understands they will go for the drink after work.)

@PeterKirkpatrick - it can just mean 'later' (my wife is from Wigan).

@MichaelHarvey, and with regard to your preferred burning, this is the one you married after?

@PaulTanenbaum - yes, indeed! She is my second wife; in fact, to be precise she is my civil partner.

And I'm from the other side of the world, so I happily defer to your Northern wisdom.

After can be used as an adverb, synonym of afterward(s). Please use a proper dictionary or grammar book for learning and understanding English, not a random YouTube video.

As they are round the dinner table, he probably means 'after the meal'.

Dad taking his daughters to a pub -- not a typical American scenario :-)

@Yunus Yes, the preposition "after" can occur with an NP complement ("I saw her after the meeting", or with a subordinate clause as complement ("I saw her after we arrived") or with no complement at all ("I saw her after").

Based on the comments, it seems to be perfectly natural in regional UK Northern dialects, with the same meaning as "later"
In American English, we would probably say afterwards.
